# How to enable webkit to generate reports for forms?

Tags: python, css, webkit, odoo, openerp-8

I want to ask if I can create openerp reports according to my current form. I am using Webkit for reporting in OpenERP-7 . The print button gives me options of "Stock Level Forecast" , "Pricelist" and "Product Labels". But if I want all my fields on the form, then can it be done with Webkit ? If yes then do guide me please.

Thanks to all

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can include all the fields on the webkit report. it is up to you how you are creating your mako template.

Here is the link which can be helpful to create webkit report

http://www.serpentcs.com/serpentcs-rml-to-webkit-report-guide